# Convert tuple value to column names

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot, crosstab

Got something like:

```
+-------+------+-------+
| count |  id  | grade |
+-------+------+-------+
|     1 |    0 | A     |
|     2 |    0 | B     |
|     1 |    1 | F     |
|     3 |    1 | D     |
|     5 |    2 | B     |
|     1 |    2 | C     |
```

I need:

```
+-----+---+----+---+---+---+
| id  | A | B  | C | D | F |
+-----+---+----+---+---+---+
|   0 | 1 |  2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|   1 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|   2 | 0 |  5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
```

I don't know if I can even do this. I can group by id but how would you read the count value for each grade column?

Comment: is the first table the result of a query? if so, show your original table structure too as there may be an easier solution to get the final result.

Comment: Yes it is! I have something that essentially gives id, class, grade. I grouped by ID and grade and counted tuples in that.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable(_count INT,id INT , grade VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #MyTable( _count ,id  , grade )
SELECT 1,0,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,0,'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,'F' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1,'D' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,2,'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,'C' 


SELECT *
FROM
(
 SELECT _count ,id  ,grade
 FROM #MyTable
)A
PIVOT
(
  MAX(_count) FOR grade IN ([A],[B],[C],[D],[F])
)P
```

Comment: It is about PostgreSQL, not MS SQL.

Comment: Ok but not mentioned anywhere.Its helps for MS SQL users

Comment: It's tagged PostgreSQL. Won't get any clearer than this. This answer is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "pivot" table or "cross-tabulation". You can use a combination of aggregation and `CASE` statements, or, more elegantly the **`crosstab()`** function provided by the additional module `tablefunc`. All basics here:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Since not all keys in `grade` have values, you need the 2-parameter form. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
        'SELECT id, grade, count FROM table ORDER BY 1,2'
       , $$SELECT unnest('{A,B,C,D,F}'::text[])$$
       ) ct(id text, "A" int, "B" int, "C" int, "D" int, "F" int);
```

Comment: Why not simply `VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('F')` instead of creating an array and then immediately decomposing it?

Comment: @Patrick: Because it's shorter syntax for more than a few items.

Comment: IMO an article about crosstab/pivot/dynamic pivot should be written in the Documentation section. Unfortunately my English is not so good...

Comment: @Abelisto: Maybe. I have not warmed up to the whole concept of SO "Documentation", which should really be called something like "Canonical Examples". Postgres has an excellent official documentation that's kept up to date by the project. I am not convinced we should start a parallel Postgres documentation beyond established SO features. But that's really a discussion for meta - and it has been discussed *a lot* there.

Comment: Is there a way without using crosstab?